# Mapping of Field Extensions of Prime power

Tags: extension-field, profinite-groups

If we have $q= p^f$ and $\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$.
A supernatural number n is defined in following way: $n = \prod _{p \ prime} p^{n_p}$ with $n_p \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$.

I want to show that we have a bijective map $n \to \mathbb{F}(n)$ where $\mathbb{F}(n) := \mathbb{F}_{p^n } $ with covariant relation $\mathbb{F}(m) \subset \mathbb{F}(n)$ if and only if $m | n$.

My last try:
If $n$ is only natural so I can define $F(n) = \{a \in \bar{\mathbb{F}_q}| f_n(a) =0 \ for \ f_n(X) = X^{q^n}-X\}$ what obviously concerving the relation above. Is there a way to "transfer" this argumentation in appropriate way for to a arbitrary supernatural $n$?

Comment: My idea was to define a map $\phi$ firstly from natural numbers to finite prime power extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q$ (so $n \to \phi(n) := F(n)$ where $F(n)$ is a field extention of $\mathbb{F}_q$ as defined above with $[F(n):\mathbb{F}_q]=n$) and then to "extend" it to supernatural numbers / infinite field extensions but I don't see how...

Comment: Your question is really unclear to the reader, try being *much more clear*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For $p$ prime, $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$  is defined as a finite field with $p^n$ elements, which implies $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$ is a multiplicative group with $p^n-1$ elements, so its elements satisfy $a^{p^n-1} = 1$ and the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are roots of $X^{p^n}-X \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}[X]$.

  But $X^{p^n}-X $ has at most $p^n$ roots in the **field** $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ therefore $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is exactly the splitting field of  $X^{p^n}-X  \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

  $X^{p^m-1}-1$ divides  $X^{p^n-1}-1$ iff $p^m-1 | p^n-1$ iff $m | n$. Thus $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}  \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ iff $m | n$.
- For a formal infinite product $\mathfrak{M} = \prod q_i^{e_i}$ where the $q_i$ are distinct primes, we can define $$\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{M}} = \bigcup_{j \to \infty} \mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^{m_j}}, \qquad m_j = \prod_{i \le j} q_i^{e_i}$$

  By the preceding $\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{M}}$ is well-defined as a field, and it doesn't depend on which order we take the $q_i$.

  We obtain $\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{M}} \subset \mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{F}}$ iff $\forall i, e_i(\mathfrak{F}) - e_i(\mathfrak{M}) \ge 0$  which we can take as the definition of $\mathfrak{M}\ |\ \mathfrak{F}$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, The point that is not yet clear to me is how do you prove the injectiveness of this map: so if you have two really supernatural numbers $\mathfrak{M} \neq \mathfrak{F}$ that $\mathbb{F}_{p^\mathfrak{M}} \neq \mathbb{F}_{p^\mathfrak{F}}$? 
You have constructed $\mathbb{F}_{p^\mathfrak{M}}$ as (direct ?) limit of the $\mathbb{F}_{ p^{m_j}}$ (therefore $\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{M}} = \bigcup_{j \to \infty} \mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^{m_j}}$ with $m_j \to \mathfrak{M}$);

Comment: respectively $\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{F}} = \bigcup_{j \to \infty} \mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^{m_j '}}$ with $m_j '  \to \mathfrak{F}$.

But why the convergence of $m_j$ and $m_j '$ against different REALLY supernatural numbers lead us in this construction to different field extensions?

Comment: @KarlPeter $\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{M}} =\mathbb{F}_{\textstyle p^\mathfrak{F}}$ iff they contain the same finite fields iff $\forall i, e_i(\mathfrak{F}) = e_i(\mathfrak{M})$ (I didn't mention the case $e_i(\mathfrak{F}) = \infty$ which is not very different)